# Audit Log nodejs - mysql

Tags: node.js

Looking for a simple solution for model audit logs in nodejs using mysql.

The solution should be able to create a new model and version any model changes into the new model and obviously save into the mysql table.

A solution similar to https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit would work.

Any similar solutions out there?

Comment: i want to implement the same, have you find solution for your problem?